# Rename file in another directory without repeating path

Tags: bash

I often need to make a small change to a file nested several directories below my current working directory. Since it's only one file, and globbing/scripting would be overkill, I make the change manually.

For example, I need to rename the file `blaz.txt` in ./foo/bar/blee to `foobar.txt`:

```
. 
|--foo
  |--bar
     | blee
       |-- blaz.txt
```

Normally, I do this by `cd`'ing to `blee` and running `mv blaz.txt foobar.txt` for single files. I know I could type out the full paths (resting on some handy tab completions to speed things up), but I would prefer something quicker.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With brace expansion:

```
mv foo/bar/blee/{blaz,foobar}.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

```
> touch tmp/foo/bar/baz
> rename baz boo tmp/foo/bar/baz
> ls -l tmp/foo/bar/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 hl hauke 0 May 29 23:08 boo
```

Comment: This is a really interesting alternative to brace expansion, but unfortunately ``rename`` is not included in some of the *nix flavors I use.

Comment: Note that this depends on the version of `rename` your distro ships - Debian and derivatives use `perl-rename` as their `rename` (and that has an entirely different, perl-regex-based, syntax).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a subshell.

`( cd foo/bar/blee ; mv blaz.txt boo.txt )`

But I had to +1 the braces example.  That is excellent.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the path `foo=/tmp/foo/bar` in your environment and use it as shortcut.

```
 mv $foo/blaz.txt $foo/foobar.txt
```

or

```
 mv $foo/{blaz,foobar}.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't end up getting too messy you should be able to create a symlink and pass the commands to it itself.

A guide to creating symlinks: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/

Update from comment below:
`ln -s /directory/thats/super/long/and/a/pita/ /etc/goats/` and then `mv /etc/goats/foo.txt /etc/goats/bar.txt` 
Worth a try.

Comment: Could you give an example? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: If you rename a symlink, you won't rename the file it point to.

Comment: `ln -s /directory/thats/super/long/and/a/pita/ /etc/goats/`
and then `mv /etc/goats/foo.txt /etc/goats/bar.txt`

Worth a try.